# Decrypt a PGP file in an Azure Storage blob using Runbook Power Shell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-blob-storage, blob, pgp

I'm trying to decrypt a PGP file using the PSPGP PowerShell module.The file is stored in an azure blob container.
As I'm not too familiar with PowerShell, here's the script I'm using:

```
param (  
    [Parameter()]  
    [string] $storageAccount = "mystorageaccount",   
    [string] $srcBlob = "/input/file.txt.pgp",
    [string] $srcContainer = "myontainer",  
    [string] $destContainer = "myontainer",
    [string] $pgpprivatekey = "/input/PGPKeyPrivate.pgp",
    [string] $ResourceGroup = "myressourcegroup" 
      )

# Connect to Azure  

Write-Verbose -Message 'Connecting to Azure'

$AzureContext = (Connect-AzAccount -Identity).context  
Disable-AzContextAutosave -Scope Process  
$AzureContext = Set-AzContext -SubscriptionName $AzureContext.Subscription -DefaultProfile $AzureContext   
$storageContext = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccount -UseConnectedAccount  

   try {
        $accKey = (Get-AzStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup -StorageAccountName $storageAccount).Value[0]
        $context_storageAcct = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccount -StorageAccountKey $accKey
        write-output $context_storageAcct
    }
    catch {
        $errors += [PSCustomObject]@{Item = "azcontext"; Error = $_.Exception }
        write-output "error get AZcontext"
    }

# decript PGP Files
try {
Unprotect-PGP -FilePathPrivate $srcContainer+$pgpprivatekey  -Password "mypsw" -FolderPath $srcContainer+$srcBlob -OutputFolderPath $srcContainer+"/input"
} 
    catch   
    {  
        $errmsg = $_.Exception.Message    
        Write-Output $errmsg   
    }
```

when I execute the runbook here is what it returns:
[image]

Someone can help me please to fix the script?

thank you.

Comment: Are you passing a valid private key to the script?  Error says private key doesn't exist.

Comment: yes, the private kay file "PGPKeyPrivate.pgp" it's stored in the same "Blobe Azure" directory as the file I want to decript.

Comment: Why is the suffix of the private key ".pgp"? Is this a valid private key file? How did you get this file with this suffix? The keys usually have a suffix of ".asc"

Comment: After code fails type : Write-Host $srcContainer+$pgpprivatekey $srcContainer+$srcBlob  The filenames should look like this example : https://github.com/EvotecIT/PSPGP/blob/master/Examples/Example-DecryptFile.ps1

Answer (score 1):

> WARNING: Unprotect-PGP - Remove PGP encryption failed because private key not given.

I tried the same script in my environment and got the same error.

[image]

The above error occurred because it's not fetching the file path from blob storage or may be the command cannot be executed with blob storage.

Alternatively, you can download both **`pgpprivatekey`** and **`file.txt.pgp`** to your local path.

You can run the **`unprotect-pgp`** command with a specified path.

**Command:**

```
 try{
Unprotect-PGP -FilePathPrivate "C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\<Your-pgpprivatekey>.asc"  -Password "xxxx" -FolderPath "C:\Users\xxxx\Documents\sample.txt.pgp" -OutputFolderPath "C:\Users\v-xxxx\Documents\input"
Write-Host "The file is decrypted to outputfolderpath"
}
  catch   
    {  
        $errmsg = $_.Exception.Message    
        Write-Output $errmsg   
    }
```

[image]

The above command decrypted the file successfully and the file was saved in the input folder.

Now using **`azcopy`** tool you can upload to your container.

```
azcopy copy "C:\Users\xxx\Documents\input\sample.txt" "https://venkat123.blob.core.windows.net/test?sv=2022-11-02&ss=bfqt&srt=co&sp=rwdlacupiytfx&se=2023-07-26T19:52:33Z&st=2023-07-26T11:52:33Z&spr=https&sig=xxxxxx" --recursive=true
```

**Output:**

```
INFO: Scanning...
INFO: Any empty folders will not be processed, because source and/or destination doesn't have full folder support
Job 0547e87xxxxxxxxxe has started
Log file is located at: C:\Users\xxx\.azcopy\054xxx.log
INFO: azcopy.exe: A newer version 10.19.0 is available to download
100.0 %, 1 Done, 0 Failed, 0 Pending, 0 Skipped, 1 Total, 2-sec Throughput (Mb/s): 0.0033

Job 054xxxxxx summary
Elapsed Time (Minutes): 0.0335
Number of File Transfers: 1
Number of Folder Property Transfers: 0
Total Number of Transfers: 1
Number of Transfers Completed: 1
Number of Transfers Failed: 0
Number of Transfers Skipped: 0
TotalBytesTransferred: 839
Final Job Status: Completed
```

[image]

**Reference:**

[Upload files to Azure Blob storage by using AzCopy v10 | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-blobs-upload#upload-a-file)

Comment: thank you for your reply, unfortunately, for reasons of confidentiality, it is not possible to transfer files to a local machine, all processing must be carried out on the azure blob.